# Why there is different register address for sstatus an mstatus although they are different view of same register?

Tags: cpu-architecture, privileges, riscv, instruction-set

> The sstatus register is a subset of the mstatus register.
> In a straightforward implementation, reading or writing any field in sstatus is equivalent to
> reading or writing the homonymous field in mstatus.

This is taken from the [riscv-privledeged-20211203.pdf](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual/releases/download/Priv-v1.12/riscv-privileged-20211203.pdf).
We have two registers and consume different address spaces for both `status` for `S` and `M` modes. Also, storing information in two different registers seems more comprehensive(I guess).
So what is the reason to use `sstatus` as a subset of `mstatus` instead of a separate register? Is there any performance optimization on this?

If it is the optimized way, why does the spec allocate different register addresses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have different privilege levels.

In Section 2.2, you can see that `sstatus` has privilege SRW, meaning it can be read and written from supervisor (S) mode.  On the other hand, `mstatus` is MRW, so it can be read and written from machine mode (M), which apparently is a higher privilege level.

So effectively, it means that S mode is only allowed access to a subset of the bits in `mstatus`.

An alternative way to implement this would have been to make `mstatus` accessible at both levels, but add extra microcode so that if it is accessed from level S, the more sensitive bits are masked off.  But that would be a little more complicated.  There must already be a mechanism that checks privilege level on access to any CSR register, so by treating `sstatus` as its own register with its own address, we can just use this existing mechanism.  Once this check is passed, accesses to `sstatus` can simply be treated as accesses to `mstatus` with the sensitive bits *unconditionally* masked.